# Cassandra data clone to another cassandra database(different servers)

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.1, bigdata, database

My question is above mentioned, have a cassandra database and wanted to use another server with this data. How can i move this all keyspace's data?

I have snapshots but i dont know can i open it to another server.

Thanks for your helps

Comment: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/ops_snapshot_restore_new_cluster.html

Comment: does the new server have the same token / virtual nodes ?

Comment: ah no,we have decided to move another cloud company.(amazon to IBM)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you have limited options to move data across clouds primarily COPY command or sstableloader (https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/migrating.html) or if you plan to maintain a like-to-like setup (same number of nodes) across clouds then simply copying snapshots under data would work.

If you are moving to IBM Softlayer, you maybe able to use software-defined storage solutions that get deployed on bare metal and provide features like thin clones that will allow you to create clones of cassandra clusters in matter of minutes and provide incredible space savings. This is rather useful for creating clones for dev/test purposes. Checkout [Robin Systems](http://www.robinsystems.com/solutions/robin-for-databases/), you may find them interesting.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to migrate your data from one cluster to another is using the [sstableloader](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.x/cassandra/tools/toolsBulkloader.html) tool. This will allow you to stream the contents of your sstables from a local directory to a remote cluster. In this case the new cluster can also be configured differently and you also don't have to worry about assigned tokens.